# How do I execute JavaScript from an iMacro script?

Tags: javascript, imacros

How do I execute JavaScript from an iMacro script?

> URL GOTO=javascript:alert("TEST");

The Javascript works fine when pasting it into the address bar (by putting "`javascript:`" in front of the code) but unfortunately iMacros does not recognize this as a valid URL.

So since this doesn't work, what's the correct way to run JavaScript from an iMacro script?

Answer (score 4):

Try something without a dialog. For example: `URL GOTO=javascript:console.log("TEST");` or `URL GOTO=javascript:function<SP>test(){status="TEST"};void<SP>test();`

Comment: I think there should be addon to enable js execution in navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

make a separate java-script file and then call it from your macro using

> URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=your-javascript.js

note that this method is not actually perfect cause imacros does not support calling javascript files from within macros, so this is a workaround and may have certain side effects - enterprise imacros support callback for javascript files.